# how can i get plugins for gedit for zooming the text file?

Tags: gedit

i want the gedit plugin for zooming the text in file.when i clicked on the Edit-preference-plugin it shows me below message,where i couldn't find plugin.[image]

Comment: Is Ctrl+Mouse Scroll what you are looking for?

Comment: it is working in the webbrowser also for zooming the text.That's why i tried it in gedit but it's not working! so i'm looking for plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If gedit has missing plugins, make sure you have the `gedit-plugins` installed.

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
```

After that, (you probably need to restart gedit) you will have a plugin called "Text Size".
Make sure the plugin is enabled, and you will be able to "zoom" (i.e. change font size) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Mouse Wheel.

[image: gedit Plugins]

This is the list of plugins available in the `gedit-plugins` package

```
$ apt-cache show gedit-plugins
[...]
 The following plugins are included:
  * Git: Git differences
  * Bookmarks: Easy document navigation with bookmarks
  * Bracket Completion: Automatically adds closing brackets.
  * Character Map: Insert special characters just by clicking on them.
  * Code comment: Comment out or uncomment a selected block of code.
  * Color Picker: Pick a color from a dialog and insert its hexadecimal representation.
  * Color Scheme Editor: Source code color scheme editor
  * Commander: Command line interface for advanced editing
  * Dashboard: A Dashboard for new tabs
  * Draw Spaces: Draw Spaces and Tabs
  * Git: Git differences
  * Join/Split Lines: Join several lines or split long ones
  * Multi Edit: Edit document in multiple places at once
  * Smart Spaces: Forget you're not using tabulations.
  * SyncTeX: Synchronize between LaTeX and PDF with gedit and evince.
  * Embedded Terminal: Embed a terminal in the bottom pane.
  * Text Size: Easily increase and decrease the text size
  * Word Completion: Word completion using the completion framework
[...]
```

Comment: It is not necessary to restart Gedit. After the installation of 'gedit-plugins',  then activate the 'Text Size' plugin and you are good (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  and Gedit 3.18.3).

Comment: Warning: It seems gedit-plugins no longer pulls in gedit-plugin-text-size; you may have to install it explicitly.

Answer (score 10):

SOME WAYS OF FIXING:

1. `$ sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins  -y`

Go to gedit preference  > plugins and activate  what you need.

If   text size  doesn't appear  , so  :

2. googling :  Looking for gedit plugin text size . I found this : https://packages.debian.org/buster/gedit-plugin-text-size .

   Package exist .

   *** and do this :

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install gedit-plugin-text-size   -y
   ```

   Then reopen gedit: preference  > plugins. You'll see "text-size" appear.

( THIS WORKED FOR ME ) .

Comment: Confirmed - I'm on Ubuntu 19.04, and installing gedit-plugins didn't pull in gedit-plugin-text-size; I had to install it manually.

Comment: THANK YOU. I have no idea what the deal is with gedit, but this was the only fix that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of Gedit plugins from Gnome https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Plugins unless what you wanted is to change the font size to larger.

Comment: That link is dead; I think this is the new version: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/ShippedPlugins