# Gedit Text size plugin keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit

From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/409635/163331) the way to zoom in/out of text in Gedit is by installing `gedit-plugins`, enabling the `text size` plugin and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Mouse scroll to zoom in/out.

This doesn't work in Gedit 3.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. There are no changes on the text size - either increase or decrease.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> doesn't work either and the only way is to select the menu directly in "View" -> "Increase/Decrease font size". To get the 'right' zoom, you will have to do this multiple times - for me it came to 8 times.

How can I get the keyboard shortcuts working? It's tiring and time wasting.

**EDIT**

Another interesting question (check the first comment): [How to zoom in and out of text in Gedit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108967/how-to-zoom-in-and-out-of-text-in-gedit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit-plugins/+bug/1000193).

On the meanwhile, these shortcuts work on Gedit 3.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04:

- Zoom In: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>
- Zoom out: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>
- Normal size: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + mouse wheel don't work in either zoom in or zoom out.

Comment: in my case, only Ctrl+scroll up/down works. I use Macbook pro 2012.